# How to remove amCharts container padding?

Tags: javascript, padding, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm trying to remove the padding / margin of amChart.

[image]

I've tried to use `am4core.percent(100)` for `chart.width` and `chart.plotContainer.width`.

I'm browsing the web for a bit, without success. I don't know if it's because of the amChart logo in bottom left creating that padding.

Comment: chart.padding(0, 0, 0, 0);

Answer (score 5):

For **AmCharts 5** the correct way for setting **padding** to **0** is:

```
  const chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
    paddingRight: 0,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    paddingLeft: 0,
  }));
```

Have a look at their doc: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/reference/xychart/#paddingBottom_setting

Also knowing how a XY chart is structured in AmCharts 5 can be very handy: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/xy-chart-containers/

Answer (score 4):

```
    chart.paddingTop = 0;
    chart.paddingBottom = 0;
    chart.paddingLeft = 0;
    chart.paddingRight = 0;
```

[Example: https://codepen.io/rsaraceni/pen/xxRGGvQ](https://codepen.io/rsaraceni/pen/xxRGGvQ)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using amcharts 5 I got a slightly different answer. The paddings is part of the charts "_settings" attribute

```
chart._settings.paddingRight = 0;
chart._settings.paddingLeft = 0;
chart._settings.paddingTop = 0;
chart._settings.paddingBottom = 0;
```